# How can I add bundle to karaf Custom Distribution?

Tags: apache-karaf, karaf, karaf-maven-plugin

I create karaf Custom Distribution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.me</groupId>
    <artifactId>root-karaf</artifactId>
    <packaging>karaf-assembly</packaging>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <version>4.0.4</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId>
            <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
            <type>kar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
            <classifier>features</classifier>
            <type>xml</type>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
                <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.4</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- no startupFeatures -->
                    <startupFeatures>

                    </startupFeatures>

                    <installedFeatures>
                    </installedFeatures>
                    <bootFeatures>
                        <feature>standard</feature>
                        <feature>eventadmin</feature>
                        <feature>scr</feature>
                    </bootFeatures>

                    <excludedArtifactIds>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    </excludedArtifactIds>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now I want create example bundle and add to this Distribution or for example add this: `<bundle>wrap:mvn:com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0</bundle>` ti rhis Distribution. I thried this:

```
<bootFeatures>
                        <feature>standard</feature>
                        <feature>eventadmin</feature>
                        <feature>scr</feature>
                        <bundle>wrap:mvn:com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0</bundle>
                    </bootFeatures>
```

But it nit work

I create feature.xml and put to resources

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<features xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="platform-features"
          xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.0.0"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.0.0 http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.0.0">

    <feature name="platform" version="${project.version}" install="auto">
        <details>Service Platform</details>
        <feature>test</feature>
    </feature>


    <feature name="test" version="4.0.4" install="auto">
        <bundle>mvn:com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0</bundle>
    </feature>
</features>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can not add bundle directly to `<bootFeatures>`. You should create your own feature that contains this bundle and add that feature to `bootFeatures`. Also, when you create your feature you don't need the `wrap:` part! `gson 2.8` is already an OSGi bundle!

Comment: Thank you kep! I created the futures.xml. Where do I put it (the file itself) and how do I connect and configure it so that from this futures the bundles get into the assembly?

Comment: Create another module with your feature, add it as dependency to your dependency list, add the name of the feature to the list of bootfeatures, then your set